# BluetoothChat transmitted data is split

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using Bluetooth to transmit data in my app to my device, where I display the received data.

I used parts of the `BluetoothChat` component to connect with other devices and manage the transmission. If I send data from another smartphone using `BluetoothChat`, it is correctly displayed in my app. But if I send the data from an external bluetooth module (*`Rn42`* in my case), the received data are sometimes split.

For example, if I send `35`,  what I actually receive is `3` and `5`. This also happens if I send the data using the `BluetoothChat` component.

Do you know what could be the problem ?

Comment: happens only some times or all time it splits data ..??

Comment: the data is split most of the time. But not always.

Comment: Are trying to communicate with some kind of mcu(Arduino, stm32)? If you are using Arduino you could create a string buffer like this "char inBytes = Serial.read(); 
      String buffer += inBytes;" Arduino Uno Serial buffer size is 64 bytes so some data are splitted

Comment: even i had that problem.. may be the device (Rn42) dont send data at once , so while receiving u serialize and put together

Comment: Did you solve your problem like that?